# Choosing Firewalls

Tags: firewall, hardware

What are the specs that you look for in a firewall? I'm looking at concurrent sessions and throughput. The sales person i spoke to is looking at number of users but that is not in the detailed specs. I'm running into the sales pitch vs. real baseline metrics discontinuity and i'm at a loss...

Comment: "number of users" is one of those numbers that sounds good but means little. What are those users doing - there's a big difference between 1000 users at a company where everyone does a bit of research on the web and 1000 users at a media company where people stream about a dozen things at once and might as well live on youtube clone websites.

Answer (score 1):

Price, ease of management, and knowledge/mindshare.

So for most small office/business solutions, I can get by with lower-end Cisco ASA devices (5505, 5510), for example. Price is reasonable in that realm. And the knowledge issue isn't a problem due to the number of engineers familiar with the equipment.

But rather than recommend a product, I'd insist that the metrics that are important to you should be the same metrics that guide your search.

Comment: what other metrics are there besides throughput and concurrent sessions?

Comment: Nobody was ever fired for buying Cisco.  :)

Comment: Hardware design (cooling, form-factor, internal redundancy), simultaneous VPN peers, packets-per-second, clustering, VLAN capabilities, # of ports.